# Using C from Python

Tags: python, c, ctypes, network-interface

I want to know the names of the NetworkInterfaces from python, but it seems it's not possible from python so I'm using this C code:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")

PyObject* GetInterfaces (PyObject* self){
    ULONG buflen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);
    IP_ADAPTER_INFO *pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)malloc(buflen);

    if (GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &buflen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
        free(pAdapterInfo);
        pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)malloc(buflen);
    }

    if (GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &buflen) == NO_ERROR) {
        for (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *pAdapter = pAdapterInfo; pAdapter; pAdapter = pAdapter->Next) {
            printf("%s (%s)\n", pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String, pAdapter->Description);
        }
    }

    if (pAdapterInfo) free(pAdapterInfo);
    return 0;
}

static char interfaces_docs[] =
    "GetInterfaces( ): prints the interfaces name and IP\n";

static PyMethodDef interfaces_funcs[] = {
    {"GetInterfaces", (PyCFunction)GetInterfaces, 
     METH_NOARGS, interfaces_docs},
    {NULL}
};

void initinterfaces(void)
{
    Py_InitModule3("interfaces", interfaces_funcs,
                   "Interfaces Module");
}
```

Is this good? And what are the steps to importing it into Python with ctypes? How can I do it? Also is there a way to return a list of tuples instead of printing it? Do I need to compile it? If I do how can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this good?

Almost. Never return 0/null as a `PyObject*` unless you're [signaling an exception](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#intermezzo-errors-and-exceptions); instead incref `Py_None` and return it. And you may want to add actual error checking code as well.

> And what are the steps to importing it into Python with ctypes? How can I do it?

What you've written doesn't need ctypes, since it's an actual Python module written in C. Use `import interfaces` after compiling the code to interfaces.pyd.

> Also is there a way to return a list of tuples instead of printing it? Do I need to compile it? If I do how can I?

With the normal [list](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html) and [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/tuple.html) functions; create the object and set each element in turn as required.

Comment: Thank you! what tools are used to compile .c to .pyd?

Comment: A C compiler. A .pyd file is just a renamed DLL.

Comment: I tried to run 'gcc interfaces.c' and it said ' Python.h: No such file or directory'

Comment: You need to tell gcc where it can find Python.h.

Comment: I tried putting interfaces.c in the include folder where Python.h is found, and it's still saying this